# rst2html.py <link> style sheet

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils, rst2html.py

Using Docutils's rst2html.py, is it possible to include a link to a stylesheet in the `head`: `<head>...<link rel=stylesheet href="friendly+dinosaur.css" />...</head>`?

So, to clarify, I'm *not* interested in generating `<style>...{{ contents on friendly+dinosaur.css }}...</style>` or using `@import`.

I've noticed there's the `--link-stylesheet` although it takes no arguments, instead just adding a reference to `html4css1.css`. `--stylesheet-path` appears to be unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The `--link-stylesheet` flag sets stylesheet linking behavior on (rather than embedding) and then you give the name of the stylesheet you want to link with `--stylesheet my_style.css`. `html4css1.css` showed up because it's the default stylesheet.